# Issue with uploading multiple files on a single html page using php

Tags: php, html, file, upload

I am trying to build a web page where users can edit images portrayed on their public pages. There are 3 images that display on their public page and I've set up 3 HTML forms in order to handle the 3 separate files.

I only have 1 listed below because once I figure out the fix to 1 I'll be able to duplicate the fix to the other 2,

I have other upload pages on my website and they work fine, but for some reason this page is giving me trouble. I can select a file but when I want to upload it my php code doesn't read that there is anything being posted.

*I've commented out the function call (I know it works) I just need to know why my php code won't read that there is a file there.

If I had to guess it'd be something with how it's named or how it's being tossed to the php code.

The code looks like this:

```
                                            <div class="academic" style="width:250px;">
        <br>
        <?php 




        if(isset($_FILES['aca']) === true)
        {
            echo 'please print';  //It doesn't
            if(empty($_FILES['aca']['name']) === true)
            {
            echo 'Please choose a file! <br>';
            }
            else
            {

                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['aca']['name']; 

                $file_extn = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['aca']['tmp_name'];
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                print_r($_FILES['aca']['tmp_name']);
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<br>';
                if(in_array($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {

                //upload_image($file_temp,$file_extn);

                echo 'You have uploaded a picture!';
                echo '<b><h3>Press submit again to finish the upload</h3></b>';
                //echo "<script>window.top.location='../hidden/viewPNM.php?id=$permi'</script>";


                }
                else
                {
                echo 'Incorrect File Type!! <br> Allowed: ';
                echo implode(', ', $allowed);

                }

            }

        }


        ?>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="aca" id="aca"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>

        </div>
        </span>
```

Comment: Are you getting any output at all after you post?

Comment: Nothing is happening. The page seems to reload itself but there is nothing printed at any point. Any redirect or function call is commented out and shouldn't redirect or send to the functions page but it doesn't print out "Please print" so it doesn't think that $_FILES['aca'] is set.

Comment: Please, post the form code as well. I cannot find anything wrong with your code. I would try to change `if(isset($_FILES['aca']) === true)` to `if(isset($_FILES['aca'])` (remove the === true)

Comment: The form code is posted below the php as it is set up in my actual code. The form is as follows:`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="aca" id="aca"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>`

Comment: Edited my comment, please read it again and try what I've added. :)

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work :(

Comment: Check for isset post submit not FILES

Comment: Have you got error reporting turned on?

Comment: Yes I have turned error reporting on. It's not throwing an error, it's just not being read by the php code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...here is what you can try to do:

> Move the whole PHP code UNDER the form code. I remember that sometimes wierd bugs with that were happening, and the code didnt run

If that doesnt work, do following:

> 1. Change `<input type="file" name="aca" id="aca">` to  `<input multiple="true" type="file" name="aca[]" />`
> 2. Add this code above the submit button: `<input type="hidden" name="sendfiles" value="Send Files" />`
> 3. Replace `if(isset($_FILES['aca']) === true)` with `if(isset($_POST['sendfiles']))`

If this doesn't work, I can offer you a way to allow multiple files being uploaded from one button. (Took the code from my website I made before)

Comment: Did you check your Php.ini if your website allows upload of files?

Comment: Yes I did make sure php.ini allows uploaded files.